# Is there a way to encode a value/result when signaling a WaitHandle or similar class?

Tags: c#

As far as I can see `AutoResetEvent` and `ManualEvent` simply control a single signal for cross-thread communication.
Often you would want to know some sort of result in the waiting thread and I can only see the option of storing a class member which is accessed by each thread e.g.:

```
this.WaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
DoStuff();
WaitHandle.WaitOne();
lock(this._lock)
{
 if(this.Result ...){...}
}
```

---

```
void DoStuff()
{
 ...
    lock(this._lock)
    {
     this.Result = ...;
    }
    this.WaitHandle.Set();
}
```

This is a bit cumbersome so I wondered if there is something built in that will let me pass a value when signalling?

Comment: This is a contrived example and someone is probably going to say I should just `await DoStuff();` but the real code is more complicated, this is deliberately simplified

Comment: A `TaskCompletionSource<T>` can be useful there, even if you're not using `async` / `await` in the rest of the code. For plain old threads, monitors are still an appropriate strategy -- and note that you may not need separate events in that case (`while (myResult == null) Monitor.Wait(lock);`, `myResult = result; Monitor.PulseAll(lock)`).

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to use the `async` patterns consistently in all your code.

If you want to actually block execution and wait for the result to be available in a blocking way using traditional methods, you can use a `BlockingCollection<T>` as a channel to both communicate the result of the operation and that the operation is finished at the same time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BlockingCollection<string> blockingQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    // Start DoStuff on parallel thread
    Task.Run(() => DoStuff(blockingQueue));

    // Wait for DoRun to finish AND get the result at the same time
    string result = blockingQueue.Take();

    MessageBox.Show(result);
}


private void DoStuff(BlockingCollection<string> result)
{
    // Simulate work
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // return result
    result.Add("SomeResultValue");
}
```

This also allows you to have two threads adding stuff to the queue and retrieving stuff from the queue at the same time in parallel, the consumer always blocking as long as there is no new data available.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BlockingCollection<string> blockingQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    // Start DoStuff on parallel thread
    Task.Run(() => DoStuff(blockingQueue));

    // Wait for something to be returned from DoStuff and handle it
    foreach (string data in blockingQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(data + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Finished");
}


private void DoStuff(BlockingCollection<string> result)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        // Simulate work
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // return result
        result.Add("Result number " + i);
    }

    // Signal we are done
    result.CompleteAdding();
}
```

If you use a `BlockingCollection` with `BoundedCapacity`set to 1, trying to add to the collection would actually wait until the previous value has been removed.

Comment: My real case is two threads doing different things, but _sometimes_ one needs to wait on another, so signalling is the easier mechanism than creating `Task`s. Anyway, using `BlockingCollection.Take` _as_ a WaitHandle with return value is still quite neat